# Use Textmate (or any arbitrary application) with Lion's "Versions" feature?

Tags: macos, textmate, versions, latex

I'm writing a thesis in LaTeX with TextMate. I want very simple, very automated version control. Nothing complicated! Just, every time I save, a new version is created so that I can easily go back in time and look at previous versions. Lion's "Versions" feature is perfect for me but doesn't work with TextMate.

Is there a plugin I could use to get this to work? Alternatively, is there a different form of version control that's super easy to use?

I realise TeXShop now has Versions support (courtesy of this question [Which text editors take advantage of Lion's Versions feature?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/which-text-editors-take-advantage-of-lions-versions-feature)), but I'd rather stick with TextMate if at all possible.

Comment: As a brief update, TextMate is now open source — if you're really keen for it to support Versions, you could try adding it yourself (though I expect it will take a lot of work). I'm not sure how the main developer will feel about that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Scouring the TextMate community and community plugins doesn't show that this feature is currently available in TextMate. [This blog post](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/textmate-2-0-alpha/) states that they're "holding back with 'lionizing' TextMate till we feel confident we can fully drop backwards compatibility".

You're not alone though, [the community](http://old.nabble.com/Lion-Version-and-Auto-Save--td32113972i20.html) seems to be [very interested](http://meetdom.com/post/8411004128/textmate-and-lion-woes) in this feature.

I don't have experience with this plugin, but the community seems to enjoy the [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/05/textmate-plug-in-projectplus) plugin.